# How do I save multiple instances of the same JS code on firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, button

Sorry I don't code much and have adapted this code, so help would be greatly appreciated.
I'm trying to emulate a shopping page where you can 'like' a product and shows number of 'likes' for each product.

What is happening:
When I click on different instances of the 'like' button they get saved as one instance on firebase and all the 'like' counters show the same number of 'likes'

What I want:
Every time I click a different instance of the 'like' button I want it saved as a different instance on firebase so the counts are different for each 'like' button.

```js
var dCounters = document.querySelectorAll('.CountLike');
[].forEach.call(dCounters, function(dCounter) {
  var el = dCounter.querySelector('button');
  var cId = dCounter.id;
  var dDatabase = firebase.database().ref('Like Number Counter').child(cId);

  // get firebase data
  dDatabase.on('value', function(snap) {
    var data = snap.val() || 0;
    dCounter.querySelector('span').innerHTML = data;
  });

  // set firebase data
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dDatabase.transaction(function(dCount) {
      return (dCount || 0) + 1;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.CountLike div {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.item-like {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.counterStat {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.heart {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.btn {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="store-action">
    <div class="CountLike" id="Like Count">
      <div class="likes">
        <span class="counterStat">0</span>
        <button class="btn"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/164008/heart.svg" class="heart" alt="the heart-like button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="store-action">
    <div class="CountLike" id="Like Count">
      <div class="likes">
        <span class="counterStat">0</span>
        <button class="btn"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/164008/heart.svg" class="heart" alt="the heart-like button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should behave as you expected assuming the dCounter.id you have is unique,  do you see more than one single field on your firebase database interface?

Comment: Yes it saves to a single field on the db. I don't know how to save them to multiple fields so that each instance is a new field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below snippet should do it for now. Both of your elements have the same id value set which is set as `id="Like Count"`
So right now you just end up writing and reading from the same field for every cell you have.

As it is also stated [on this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) you should always make sure the id values you assign are unique.

```
   <div>
    <div class="store-action">
      <div class="CountLike" id="xyz">
        <div class="likes">
          <span class="counterStat">0</span>
          <button class="btn"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/164008/heart.svg" class="heart" alt="the heart-like button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="store-action">
      <div class="CountLike" id="xyzt">
        <div class="likes">
          <span class="counterStat">0</span>
          <button class="btn"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/164008/heart.svg" class="heart" alt="the heart-like button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have realised that! Works great!